# ASP.NET 5 and Docker error: /bin/sh: [dnx,: command not found

Tags: linux, docker, asp.net-core, dnx

When I try to get a sample ASP.NET 5 beta5 application up and running on Docker, I am getting the following error on `sudo docker start -a 2c1bec440dbc` command:

> /bin/sh: [dnx,: command not found

This is my docker file:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet

COPY ./HelloWeb /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN ["dnu", "restore"]

EXPOSE 5004
ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", "." "web"]
```

The error message is kind of cryptic and I cannot seem to understand what is going wrong. The image has been built fine, packages has been restored nicely. Any idea?

Comment: I think there's a missing comma in ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", "." "web"]. Not sure that's the problem though.

Comment: @Fedalto isn't mine (above) the same?

Comment: It should be ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", ".", "web"]

Comment: @Fedalto yes, that was it! Can you put this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a missing comma in the ENTRYPOINT line.

This leads docker to try running a `["dnx",` command and passing `"." "web"]` as argument.

It should be

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", ".", "web"]
```